# Fetch error when refreshing page with await block in SvelteKit

Tags: node.js, node-modules, svelte-3, sveltekit

I am building a sveltekit app that crashes when I refresh the page. Below is the code for the Home page that displays a map with points. The points are fetched from an api (also running on localhost). I initially had the await call inside an onMount function (worked fine) but I thought it would be tidier to use an await block. When the app is running everything works great - I can navigate to and from the Home page and the map loads as expected. However, if I refresh the browser on the Home page or navigate directly to the Home page after starting the app it crashes.

**Update:**
I now realize that using an await block or sveltkit's load function will run the fetch function on the server side before the page loads. This appears to fail because the map component relies on window. Disabling SSR fixes the issue although I would expect that the data object could be fetched via a load function and this not interfere with component creation, i.e. SSR shouldn't need to be disabled.

Svelte page:

```
<script>
    const API_PATH = import.meta.env.VITE_API_PATH;
    import Map from '$lib/Leaflet/Map.svelte';
    import Point from '$lib/Leaflet/Vector/Point.svelte';

    const lat = -41.273;
    const lng = 173.279;
    const zoom = 15;

    async function getSites() {
        const res = await fetch(API_PATH + '/sites');
        const sites = await res.json();

        if (res.ok) {
            return sites;
        } else {
            throw new Error(sites);
        }
    }

    let promise = getSites();

</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>Home</title>
</svelte:head>

<main>
    <Map center={[lat, lng]} {zoom}>
        {#await promise then sites}
            {#each Object.values(sites['features']) as site}
                <Point lat={site['geometry']['coordinates'][1]} lng={site['geometry']['coordinates'][0]}>
                </Point>
            {/each}
        {/await}
    </Map>
</main>
```

I get the following error in terminal:

```
Got request /
file:///.../node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/install-fetch.js:6246
                        reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${error.message}`, 'system', error));
                               ^

FetchError: request to http://localhost:8000/sites failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///.../node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/install-fetch.js:6246:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}
```

And in the browser console:

```
Loading failed for the module with source “http://localhost:3000/@fs/.../.svelte-kit/runtime/client/start.js”.
```

Thanks for the support.

Comment: do you having something listening too localhost:8000?

Comment: I have an api being served on localhost:8000 if that's what you mean. I.e. if I navigate to localhost:8000/sites it returns a json object. I can see the requests being fulfilled when I navigate the app but when I refresh the page it doesn't even get a request out to the api before crashing.

Comment: do you have cors set up for the api? you are getting a connection refused error

Comment: cors are set up. see edited comment above. no connection error when making other requests to this api, only in the particular case of refreshing the page.

Comment: have you tested the end point http://localhost:8000/sites , does it connect and return a json?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the `load` function (or the simplified get function that was recently introduced) to load data ? The problem is likely due to _fetch_ being different in a server-side rendering context.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes I wasn't aware of this function. I updated the following code block but still get the same behavior.
`<script context="module"><br/>
 const API_PATH = import.meta.env.VITE_API_PATH;<br/>
 export async function load() {<br/>
  const response = await fetch(API_PATH + '/sites');<br/>
<br/>
  return {<br/>
   status: response.status,<br/>
   props: {<br/>
    sites: response.ok && (await response.json())<br/>
   }<br/>
  };<br/>
 }<br/>
</script>`

Comment: you have to at least use the fetch that is passed to the load function: `export async function load({ fetch }) {` if you haven't done so, I would recommend to read the docs on `https://kit.svelte.dev/docs` where all of this is explained.

Comment: Thanks, I believe now that the issue arises because the page is not suitable for SSR. The map component relies on window. When I disable SSR the issues go away (using a load function or await block). I thought that the two actions would be completed separately - the load function would fetch and hold the json object until the map had rendered (after window loaded) and then insert the points. But my experience indicates that the load function (or await block) cannot pass an object to a component that relies on window. Would happily be proven wrong so I don't have to disable SSR.